# How could I access the memory of a running program?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, mmap

Presuming I have a program in C:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

int main()
{
    int a = rand() % 1000;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I find the value of "a" without printing it on the console, but by accessing, with a linux terminal command, its address to read the value from it?

Or generally, how can I map all the written values of a binary without seeing its implementation (like a "blackbox")?

Comment: Like a debugger would? [`ptrace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) is your starting point.

Comment: ok, do `int b =a; printf ("a is %d\n", b);` done...

Comment: @BoBTFish More like a hacker :)) I have to "unlock" some passwords; thanks, I'll check your hint

Comment: @FlorinaBarbu please don't ask SO contributors for help with immoral/illegal activities.

Comment: @MartinJames it's a game we play at University, it's all legal

Comment: @FlorinaBarbu sure, and I always believe everything I read on the internet, after all, criminals never lie...

Comment: @MartinJames https://security.cs.pub.ro/summer-school/wiki/

Answer (score 3):

Memory is accessible via `/proc/pid/mem`, index is `/proc/pid/maps`, Python prototype is [how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux).